# delaying function execution only after completing async recursive function.

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I created a file upload form with drag on drop, which iterates recursively over the dropped folder and uploads the file and folders, and adds them to a JSTree instance.

here's the drop callback

```
function drop(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();


    //get selected node (created by jsTree)
    var parent_id = $('#treeContainer').jstree('get_selected').attr('data-attr-itemid');
    var theNodeId = $('#treeContainer').jstree('get_selected').attr('id');

    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        if (item) {
            traverseFileTree2(item,parent_id,theNodeId);
        }
    }
   //THIS RUNS BEFORE RECUSIVE FUNCTION IS COMPLETED
   addFilesToUploadQueue(filesToQueue);
}
```

and here's the recursive traversing function

```
var filesToQueue = [];
function traverseFileTree2(item, parent_id, theNodeId, path) {
    if (item.isFile) {
        item.file(function(file){
          //add parent id, and adds to array to be queued for upload
          file.parent_id = parent_id;
          filesToQueue.push(file);
        })
       return;
    }
    else if (item.isDirectory) {

       var dirName = item.name;
       var url = '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'nodes', 'action'=>'addchild'));?>';
       var data = {'parent_id':parent_id, 'name':dirName, 'type':'Directory'};

       $.post(url,data,function(result){

            //adds directory node to tree
            $("#treeContainer").jstree('open_node','#'+theNodeId);
            $("#treeContainer").jstree('create', '#'+theNodeId, 'last', result,null,true);

            parent_id = result["attr"]["data-attr-itemid"];
            theNodeId = result["attr"]["id"];
            var dirReader = item.createReader();

            dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    traverseFileTree2(entries[i], parent_id, theNodeId, path + item.name + "/");
                }
            });
    }, 'json');
}
```

}

My problem here is that the function `addFilesToUploadQueue(filesToQueue)` runs before the recursive async function `traverseFileTree2` is completed. I'd prefer not use callbacks, if this can be done using promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely the kind of problem you can attack with promises.

1. Design `traverseFileTree2()` so that it *always* returns a promise/deferred, even if you don't actually launch anything asynchronous.

   - That promise's success-handler should provide a list of files that it found.
   - If you launch a bunch of recursive calls, make a list of *their* promises and use `$.when()` to wait until they all finish before doing something with them.
2. Similarly, in your main loop, collect a list of the top-level promises (from `traverseFileTree2()`) and again use `$.when()` to combine them into a promise that is "done" when all of them are over, aggregating their file-lists. (No shared `filesToQueue` variable, it's all return values.)
3. Set `addFilesToUploadQueue()` to be called on the success of this enormous last promise, taking the promise's return data of files-to-queue

---

Here is an **UNTESTED** rewrite, but even if it's buggy hopefully enough to get the idea across:

```
function drop(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();


    //get selected node (created by jsTree)
    var parent_id = $('#treeContainer').jstree('get_selected').attr('data-attr-itemid');
    var theNodeId = $('#treeContainer').jstree('get_selected').attr('id');
    var promises = [];
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        if (item) {
            promises.push(traverseFileTree2(item,parent_id,theNodeId));
        }
    }
    $.when(promises).then(function(filesToQueue){
        addFilesToUploadQueue(filesToQueue);         
    });   
}
```

and

```
function traverseFileTree2(item, parent_id, theNodeId, path) {
    var ret = $.Deferred();

    if (item.isFile) {
        var files = [];
        // What is .file()?? I'm assuming it's synchronous right now           
        item.file(function(file){
          //add parent id, and adds to array to be queued for upload
          file.parent_id = parent_id;
          files.push(file);
        });            
        ret.resolve(files)        

    } else if (item.isDirectory) {

       var dirName = item.name;
       var url = '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'nodes', 'action'=>'addchild'));?>';
       var data = {'parent_id':parent_id, 'name':dirName, 'type':'Directory'};

       $.post(url,data,function(result){

            var promises = [];
            //adds directory node to tree
            $("#treeContainer").jstree('open_node','#'+theNodeId);
            $("#treeContainer").jstree('create', '#'+theNodeId, 'last', result,null,true);

            parent_id = result["attr"]["data-attr-itemid"];
            theNodeId = result["attr"]["id"];
            var dirReader = item.createReader();
            // Assuming readEntries() is syncrhonous
            dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    promises.push(traverseFileTree2(entries[i], parent_id, theNodeId, path + item.name + "/"));
                }
            });

            $.when(promises).then(function(){
                // IIRC each argument will be the return value of one of the promises
                var files = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
                    files.concat(arguments[i]);
                }
                ret.resolve(files);
            },function(){
                ret.fail();
            });                
       }, 'json');
    }
    return ret.promise(); // .promise() is "safer" in terms of keeping code isolated
}
```

Note that this example doesn't pay too much attention to failure cases, where one of the recursive directory-listings happens to fail.

Comment: .file() is asyncronous